# Cannot see a already started TASK in TASK APP in Alfresco Activiti

Tags: eclipse, alfresco, activiti

I am using the Activiti designer to create and deploy a process in Activiti. My process gets deployed with no errors. But when I login to Activiti App, I am unable to start the process in my Task App.

Below are the logs from my Eclipse console :

```
Mar 18, 2016 2:22:31 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [activiti.cfg.xml]
Mar 18, 2016 2:22:34 PM org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl 
INFO: ProcessEngine default created
Mar 18, 2016 2:22:34 PM org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer deploy
INFO: Processing resource myProcess.bpmn20.xml
id 40005 myProcess:12:40004
```

Below is my Junit Test :

```
public void startProcess() throws Exception 
{
RepositoryService repositoryService = activitiRule.getRepositoryService();
repositoryService.createDeployment().name("working set").addInputStream("myProcess.bpmn20.xml",
new FileInputStream(filename)).deploy();
RuntimeService runtimeService = activitiRule.getRuntimeService();

ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess");
assertNotNull(processInstance.getId());
System.out.println("id " + processInstance.getId() + " "
+ processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());
}
```

I have assigned the task to $INITIATOR. The process starts successfully, but when I log into activiti-app as an administrator, I am unable to see the tasks in the task app. Why is that ?